# Can Laravel and Drupal php servers co-exist? Can we run them simultaneously on an AWS EC2 server?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, drupal

Can Laravel and Drupal php servers co-exist? Can we run them simultaneously on an AWS EC2 server?

I am to implement something like 20 pages. 8 of them are already done using Drupal and I would like to implement the rest of them using Laravel.

Comment: Have you installed xampp on EC2 instance ?

Comment: @himanshu5136, no I did not.